# Script to execute via cronjob that deletes all files in multiple directories

Tags: script, cronjob

I'm hoping you can lend me your expertise.

I use shared hosting on Hostgator and need to figure out how to delete all .gz files in multiple directories every hour.  I think I have the cronjob command correct to do this for one directory:

```
/usr/bin/find /path/to/directory/ -type f -name '*.gz' -exec rm {} \;
```

Is that correct?

If so, how would I perform the same action, but for multiple (i.e. dozens) directories? I'm guessing I can execute one script instead of a bunch of individual cronjob but I'm new to this.  What would such a script look like? And how would I execute the script via a cronjob?

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: If your version of `find` supports it, you might want to use `-delete` instead of `-exec rm {} \;` or at least `+` instead of `\;`.

Comment: An alternative is `/usr/bin/find /path/to/directory/ -type f -name '*.gz' -print0 | xargs -0 rm` which avoids executing rm over and over for each single file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass multiple paths to `find`.

```
find /dir1 /dir2 ...
```

Comment: Thanks! And that will work for a large number of directories?

Comment: It should, although I don't know the exact maximum.